# Split a single commit to multiple commits by filename without manually going through all files

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-rewrite-history

I have a commit that has changes to 100 files. I want to split that commit to 100 commits with one commit by filename.

Currently I do `git rebase -i <startpoint>` then mark the commit I want to edit with `e` and `reset HEAD^1` followed by series of `git add && git commit -m <filename>`. This becomes tedious with multiple files.

Preferably in one line of bash without scripts. Also it should be readable enough for memorization.

---

**Update:** Ended up using ElpieKay's solution with

```
git reset HEAD^ --soft
git diff --cached --name-only --relative | while read f; do git commit -m "$f" -- "$f"; done
```

Comment: Given the file names, what's the rule to make one commit? One commit per file?

Comment: Yes, one commit per file.

Comment: How about the commit message? All are the same?

Comment: Filename as the commit message. The idea is that these intermediate commits will be combined to more clean logical entity with `git rebase -i`.

Comment: One more question, is this commit the last one on the current branch?

Comment: Yes. This will be applied to the previous commit in `git rebase -i` `e` mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose it is the last commit and the commit id is `abc123`.

Try

```
git reset abc123 --hard
git reset abc123^ --soft
git diff --cached --name-only | while read f;do git commit -m "$f" -- "$f";done
```

If anything goes wrong, run `git reset abc123 --hard` to restore.

Comment: I'm not on the git root, but I think `git diff --cached --name-only --relative` solves it. After the `--relative`` modification, it does what I want in a readable way. Thank you!

Comment: I didn't use the first `git reset abc123 --hard` though. And maybe `git reset HEAD^ --soft` would be more generic solution?

Comment: @Jaakko The first `git reset` is to make sure you are right on that commit. If you are already on that commit, it's then not necessary.